# Python and Number Generators

Tags: python

I am just dabbing by toes in the basics of python and for a simple text game I plan to make, I was just wondering how you could get a random number output by (random.randrange(1, 10) could be used to activate a part of a function.

So if it output "1" it would output a set of dialogue corresponding with whatever dialogue I had set for 1. Hope i'm semi comprehensible, thanks in advance for any of you who help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

def myFunction():
    n = random.randrange(10)
    if n==1:
        # do the stuff for the output being 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has first-class functions, so if you want to avoid a load of if, elif, elif ... statements, you can make a dictionary of the outcomes, e.g.

```
reactions = {
    1: function_one,
    2: function_two,
    3: function_three,
    ...
    10: function_ten
}
```

Then call the appropriate function like so:

```
n = random.randrange(10)
reaction = reactions[n]
reaction()
```

You could compress that all onto one line but I have broken it down for clarity.

However if you want to use a range of values to call a function, you will have to either assign the function to several keys in the dictionary or fall back to using ifs and elifs